# How do I activate console.log in aptana3

Tags: console.log, aptana3

I am using Aptana3 and having problems in activating the Console.
Any advice would be greatly appreciated.
Thank you in advance.
Khalid

I had tried following the example in the course, by right clicking on the mouse button > scrawling down the window to “inspect” > with a panel showing the console.
In my case, this is not happening.